# Edges inducing an acyclic graph

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ on $n$ vertices and $j_1,\dots,j_k$ be some edges inducing an acyclic graph. I want to show that $k$ is $n-q$, where $q$ is the number of the connected components of the acyclic graph.

I have no clue.

Comment: I guess that "inducing an acyclic graph" means "inducing an acyclic graph on n vertices". Otherwise, take a giant graph and just 1 edge: here k=1,q=1 and n is giant!

Comment: Now try to reason on a single connected component. If it has r vertices, how many edges has it? Now use the fact that the total number of vertices is n and you get an equation for the number of edges.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove acyclic graph with $n-2$ edges has exactly $2$ connected components](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4101281/prove-acyclic-graph-with-n-2-edges-has-exactly-2-connected-components)

Comment: The title of the question that I linked to in my previous comment is a special case of this question, but the answer to that question concerns the general case.