# Prove acyclic graph with $n-2$ edges has exactly $2$ connected components

Tags: graph-theory

> prove that every graph $G$ on $\{1,2,\cdots,n\}$ which is acyclic and has $n-2$ edges has exactly $2$ connected components

If it was $n-2$ then the graph was a tree which has exactly 2 connected components. But I have no idea for $n-2$ edges. I was wondering what can we say about for $n-k$ edges where $k<n?$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: Each component of an acyclic graph is a tree. Suppose that the graph has $m$ components, $C_1,\ldots,C_m$, and for $k=1,\ldots,m$ let $n_k$ be the number of vertices in $C_k$, so that $n_1+\ldots+n_m=n$.

- If $1\le k\le m$, how many edges does $C_k$ have?
- How many edges does the graph have altogether?

So what, in general, is the relationship between the number of components of an acyclic graph on $n$ vertices and its number of edges?

Comment: **Each component of an acyclic graph is a tree** then isn't there should be $k-1$ edges for each $C_k?$ There should be $\frac{m(m-1)}{2}={}^mC_2$ edges altogether. @Brian M. Scott

Comment: @WhyGraph_: Not $k-1$ edges: $n_k-1$ edges. That makes a total of $$\sum_{k=1}^m(n_k-1)$$ edges; now simplify that sum to get something that involves only $n$ and $m$.

Comment: $$\sum_{k=1}^m(n_k-1)=\sum_{k=1}^mn_k-\sum_{k=1}^m1=n-m$$ Aha, I get it.  Thanks @Brian M. Scott

Comment: @WhyGraph_: Yep, you’ve got it; you’re welcome.